Father dies and daughter notices weird relationship between her mother and her uncle
What is the name of the movie where father dies and after his death daughter notices weird relationship between her mother and her uncle? It's pretty recent movie. I think it was made in 2013.

This is probably Park Chan-Wook's Stoker. 

The Film was released in the Spring of this year.
From the jump:

India Stoker  was not prepared to lose her father and best friend Richard in a tragic auto accident. The solitude of her woodsy family estate, the peace of her tranquil town, and the unspoken somberness of her home life are suddenly upended by not only this mysterious accident, but by the sudden arrival of her Uncle Charlie, whom she never knew existed. When Charlie moves in with her and her emotionally unstable mother Evie, India thinks the void left by her father's death is finally being filled by his closest bloodline. Soon after his arrival, India comes to suspect that this mysterious, charming man has ulterior motives.

A Beautifully flawed movie.
